# What should I use 来ません or 来ません でした

Tags: grammar, tense, aspect

Which is the correct answer to the question もう ジョンさんは 来ましたか。

> いいえ, まだ ジョンさんは 来ません。

or

> いいえ, まだ ジョンさんは 来ません でした。

Comment: Related or duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/42343/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/16323/9831

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see any other answers on this yet but if you have the adverb まだ the verb will conjugate to the negative ～ていない 。So this situation will be いいえ、まだジョンさんは来ていません。

Comment: ジョンさんは来ません would mean John will not come, so ジョンさんはまだ来ません doesn't make sense. If he is to come but he hasn't yet, it is used the form ている/ていない to describe the current **state** of the situation. The "state of not having come".